# Custom client domains for my web service

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, load-balancing

I have a web service running on EC2 behind an elastic balancer. I would like to allow my clients to point their A record to my web service so they could have their domain on my server. Similar to shopify or github pages.

However, I don't want to give them the IP of the web service, I'd like the request to go though the load balancer. How can I achieve this? Should I create a small server to forward requests? How does that work?

Many thanks!

Comment: There are a lot of options, some viable, some not.  So far there are two answers here that partially solve the issue.  Do you have any sense of how many domains might be involved?  Do you expect that your customer will point their bare domain name at your service, or a subdomain of their domain, or a mix of the two?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thanks, yes, some will use the full domain name and some will use a subdomain i.e. go.domain.com. I would not like to host DNS services for my clients, I'd like to give them an IP they can point to. We are talking about a lot of clients, I don't want to configure it manually but to have it done automatically. Similarly to all those services that allow you to point your domain to their service (blogs services, web shops, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your service behind an Elastic Load Balancer, you usually do not want to use ELB DNS name (which is something like `your-service-ELB-1122334455.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com`). Instead you will configure (probably using [Route53](https://aws.amazon.com/route53/), but any DNS service will do) `CNAME` or `ALIAS` record with some friendly name, like `yourservice.yourdomain.example` (this way, name will be easier to remember, and you have the freedom to change load balancer if needed).
All your customers have to do is to create [CNAME DNS record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record) pointing their name to your friendly service DNS name, like:

```
foo-service.theirdomain.example CNAME yourservice.yourdomain.example.
```

You also need to be aware that HTTP requests will have `Host:` header containing name entered by user (in case your server/service relies on that info)

Comment: This is a solid solution *unless* the customer wants to use the apex of their domain (e.g. `example.com`) rather than a host inside their domain (e.g. `special.example.com`) because a `CNAME` at the apex of a zone is, by definition, invalid.  Standards-compliant DNS providers won't allow it.  Sketchier providers will, but even then, it will not work correctly on a consistent basis, and other capabilities for a domain with such a configuration will be partially or completely disabled, like subdomains or mail exchanger (MX) configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider using [Route53](https://aws.amazon.com/route53/) as your clients's DNS service provider might not be supporting this feature beacuse of DNS rule.

See s3.6.2 of [RFC 1034](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1034)

Amazon created a new aliasing system for Route 53. You can now map the apex of a hosted zone to an Elastic Load Balancer using an Alias record. When Route 53 encounters an Alias record, it looks up the A records associated with the target DNS name in the Alias, and returns the IP addresses from that name.

In order to allow all of our customers to benefit from this new feature, there is no charge for queries to alias records when the target is an Elastic Load Balancer.

[Associating Your Custom Domain Name with Your Load Balancer Name.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-domain-names-with-elb.html#dns-associate-custom-elb)

You can also [create a Subdomain That Uses Amazon Route 53 as the DNS Service without Migrating the Parent Domain](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreatingNewSubdomain.html).

Comment: This is valid, but it would require that OP take on the DNS hosting for the customers, either in whole or in part.  (My customer can't sign up for AWS and point an Alias at my ELB; only I can do that, because Alias records only work within the same AWS account.)